# C# timed sempahore to syncronize two threads and a single output buffer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, semaphore

**ADDED PREFACE**

Here I want better explain the scenario of my application.

I need a windows service to "convert" a SerialPort into a TCPPort. For instance let's say I have a serial ticket printer connected to a COM port for raw ascii stream and I want to access it by TCP sockets from network. The result should be that the serial printer becomes a network printer, my service should link many tcp sockets to com port.

This is the scheme:
[image]

The main problem is that the COM port has a unique connection but here I can have many simultaneous connection from network clients. I need to synchronize  writes to COMport and get output from the COMport and copy that to all connected TCP clients.

With TCPconnections I cannot know when a write stream is really close, because a network client can send a print job without closing its connection and send another job after a while.
Serial printers are inline printer and there is not a start/end command, it can simply receive ascii chars and they are printer in receiving order.
This is because I need to be sure that network input will not be mixed and I want a timer that can understand that the job is really end before relase the synchronized write lock.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have two threads: **A**, **B**.

Both threads have to write in a single output buffer by WriteToOutput() method, and I want to be sure that the output will not be mixed if both **A** and **B** want to write in the output at the same time.
For first I need a simple semaphore:

```
private object locker = new object();

public void WriteToOutput(byte[] threadBuffer)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        //... copy threadBuffer to outputBuffer
    }
}
```

But I need a little more safety to divide the outputs because a thread can empty its buffer but it can be filler right after the lock release.

So in case of concurrency if the thread **A** gets the lock, I want to wait the second thread **B** for while, let's say a tick of 1s. If in this time the thread **A** wants to write something more, it has the priority, and **B** has to wait another tick. If the thread **A** do not write for a n entire tick, then it can really relase the lock and the **B** thread can get the lock.

Comment: What's the point of the multi-threading here? It looks like all you need is asynchronous I/O. What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for correction - that's a monitor, not a semaphore.

As for the rest, this sounds like a weird multi-threaded design, and it's going to be brittle and unreliable. Make it obvious when it's safe to release the shared resource - relying on any kind of timing for synchronization is a terrible idea.

The problem is that the `WriteToOutput` method is obviously not a good point for the synchronization! If you need to ensure multiple writes from the same thread are serialized, you need to move your synchronization point somewhere else. Or, pass a `Stream` instead of `byte[]`, and read that until it's closed inside the lock - this will effectively do the same thing, move the responsibility to the callee. Just make sure you don't lock it up forever by forgetting to close the stream :) Another alternative would be to use a `BlockingCollection<byte[]>`. It's hard to tell what's the best option when we don't really know what you're *actually* trying to do.

**EDIT:**

Okay, serial port communication is about the only proper use of timing like this I can think of. Of course, it can also be a bit tricky to handle the communication on a non-realtime system.

The best way to solve this would be to have a single endpoint for all your access to the serial port which would handle the communication *and* synchronization. Instead of calling the method from your other threads, you would just post data that the endpoint would read. However, this requires you to have a way of identifying the other threads - and I'm not sure if you have something like that (perhaps the `EndPoint` of the TCP socket?). The *simplest* way would be using the `BlockingCollection`:

```
private readonly object _syncObject = new object();
public void SendData(BlockingCollection<byte[]> data)
{
  lock (_syncObject)
  {
    byte[] buffer;

    while (data.TryTake(out buffer, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    {
      // Send the data
    }
  }
}
```

This will keep reading and sending data from the queue, as long as it can get another buffer in at most second-long periods - if it takes more than a second, the method will exit and another thread will have a chance.

In the socket receive thread, you'd declare the blocking collection - this will vary based on your implementation of the receive code. If you have a single instance of some class for each of the different sockets, you can just declare it as an instance field. If not, you could use `ThreadLocal`. *This assumes you're using manual threads, one per socket* - if not, you'll need a different storage.

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _dataQueue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

private void ReceiveHandler(byte[] data)
{
  // This assumes the byte array passed is already a copy
  _data.Add(data);
  SendData(_dataQueue);
}
```

This is definitely not the best way to handle this, but it's certainly the simplest I can think of right now - it's barely any code at all, and it only uses `lock` and `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: I add a preface to better explain my scenario, please consider it and let me know if do you agree that the timed monitor is the only and the better choice. thanks!

Comment: I have a little doubt... Shouln't I syncronize the queue append instead of the queue take? Maybe I have to use TryAdd() the tcpsocket threads intead of the serialsend thread?

Comment: @Tobia Not really, in this model. You have a separate blocking collection for each of the sockets, so you'll only block on one socket source at a time. Otherwise you'd have to read from all the queues at once, which eventually gets you to a nice multiple producers -> single consumer pattern - that's the best way I mentioned, but it's far from easy. You'll have to start from scratch, pretty much, ideally staying 100% asynchronous. It would save on latency and resources, though.

Comment: @Tobia You'd still want to have the timeout on the take in any case, though - you want to send first, wait next. Oh, and `TryAdd` only works on capacity-limited `BlockingCollection` - otherwise it'll just return immediately.

Comment: Ok I understand why to use tryTake... i did not see the "out" keyword. I posted my code with your suggestion, I hope to well understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tobia Note that you're running `TcpRead` and `SyncAndSend` on the same thread in your test code - that means that you will not get an opportunity to receive more data from the same socket anyway. You'll want to at least do something like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => SyncAndSend(queue));`. Which of course wastes threads a bit, but that can hardly be avoided without making the whole code asynchronous, or using a dedicated thread for the sending along with a queue of queues, basically.

Comment: I'm a bit scared about: 1 Thread per buffer loop... with a 1M of data and 1024byte as buffer I will get 1000 threads... Can I use a single separated thread to consume the queue and use ManualResetEvent to wake it up? I update my code... I already tried it and seems that it is working.

Comment: @Tobia You don't even have to use `ManualResetEvent` - all of those classes allow you to get a wait handle. Or even better, you can use `await` with the naturally asynchronous APIs (e.g. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead of `lock`, `Task.Delay` instead of timeout/sleep etc.). Also, note that `QueueUserWorkItem` doesn't create a new thread - as long as you don't block too much, it will just queue the work items. If you avoid blocking alltogether (using the async APIs), it will rarely use more than one thread.

Comment: I don't exactly understand why I shouldn't use it, but I belive you. Thanks

Comment: @Tobia Apart from being way too low level (and "old"), it's fine to use it. I'm just saying you don't actually *have to* - you could use the static `TakeFromAny` method, for example (although you'd have to make sure to update the blocking collection array safely). Or you could have a separate (and single) queue to handle processing requests - basically, using your own queue instead of the threadpool queue. This would also allow you to avoid locking - the only shared resource would be the queues, which are thread-safe on their own. An advanced option might be using a custom `TaskScheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at ReaderWriterLockSlim.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx